# Actions in Alfresco Smart Folder

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

What define which action will be show on document/folder in smart folder? In docs I only found that some actions are not supported. In `slingshot-documentlibrary-context.xml` I found some evaluators like `evaluator.doclib.action.FolderEnableInSmartFolder` but it not work for me. I have own custom action and wanna show it on folder in smart folder search. In `share-config-custom.xml` i tried this but it still don't work.

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocLibActions">
    <actions>
        <action id="contract_check" type="javascript" label="action.contract_check" icon="folder-manage-rules">
            <param name="function">onActionSimpleRepoAction</param>
            <param name="action">contract-check</param>
            <param name="successMessage">message.action.contract_check.finished.success</param>
            <param name="failureMessage">message.action.contract_check.finished.failure</param>
            <evaluator>evaluator.doclib.action.FolderEnableInSmartFolder</evaluator>
        </action>
    </actions>
    <actionGroup id="folder-browse">
        <action index="101" id="contract_check"/>
    </actionGroup>
    <actionGroup id="folder-details">
        <action index="101" id="contract_check"/>
</actionGroup>
```

I work with Alfresco CE 7.4. On physical folders action work well.